# JavaInputDStream is not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am getting following Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.initializeLogIfNecessary(KafkaUtils.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.log(KafkaUtils.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logWarning(Logging.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.logWarning(KafkaUtils.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.fixKafkaParams(KafkaUtils.scala:157)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.<init>(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
at com.spark.kafka.JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.main(JavaDirectKafkaWordCount.java:50)
18/05/29 18:05:43 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
18/05/29 18:05:43 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at
```

Code snippet:

I am writing a simple kafka - spark streaming code in eclipse to consume the messages from kafka broker using spark streaming. Below is the code

I am trying to execute respective code it working fine utill JavaInputDStream, after that i am getting error.
evey import is fine. can some one help in this

```
 package com.spark.kafka;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import scala.Tuple2;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;

public final class JavaDirectKafkaWordCount {
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String brokers = "localhost:9092";
    String topics = "sparktestone";

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaDirectKafkaWordCount").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

    Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(topics.split(",")));
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", brokers);

    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(), ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topicsSet, kafkaParams));

    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(ConsumerRecord::value);
    JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(SPACE.split(x)).iterator());
    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1))
            .reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);
    wordCounts.print();

    jssc.start();
    jssc.awaitTermination();
}
}
```

In Pom i have added respective dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same issue, in Spark 2.3 that method is abstract. 
Conclusion, use Spark 2.2.

```
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```